# Pass main() to a function in C++

Tags: c++

I have a function cleanup()

```
void cleanup() {
// blah
}

int main() {
// many variable initializations
// call cleanup
cleanup(this); // <--- can i do this? 
}
```

Can I pass main() into a function cleanup()? 
And do the cleanup by doing things like:
this->something.close() 
and 
this->something = NULL

Thanks.

Comment: You should read up on the purpose of "this", but before that you should learn about classes.

Comment: You shouldn't need to clean up main. Once it goes out of scope (when your program ends) any variables will be returned to the stack. The only thing you would _normally_ need to worry about is dynamically allocated variables, but in the case of main, once the program ends, all those will be returned to the  OS anyway.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- you'll get better results if you ask a question about what you want to do, rather than about your idea on how to do it.

Comment: I know about classes, just wondering if something like this is possible. Yes @Hurkyl I should have done that instead of inviting the torrent of downvotes haha..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re

> **”** Can I pass `main()` into a function `cleanup()`?

No, you cannot – in a formally correct program – because you are not allowed to take the address of `main`.

Instead of a named cleanup function you can simply use C++ destructors. Let each object clean up after itself, in its destructor. That's called **RAII**: *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization* (okay, it's a silly acronym).

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question. It's just something I wondered if it is possible, and didn't really turn up in google searches.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. The `this` pointer is only available within the scope of a class, which you're not using. The `main` function is not defined within a class either.

Also, you cannot pass functions around in C++ because they're not 'first-class citizens'. You'd need to use function pointers to pass functions around, and even then, trying to pass `main` wouldn't make sense. This normally makes sense when a callback is needed, and `main` is certainly not up for that purpose.

I'd recommend you get started with an introductory tutorial to the C++ language, such as [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).